# refactoring if else statement to use Ramda.js & breaking down key value pairs into object records

Tags: javascript, if-statement, functional-programming, ramda.js

I would like to transform the below reducer function to use ramda.  instead of using the JS if else statement, how could I do this using `R.ifElse()`

```
var groupAndSumBy = (objKey) => 
    R.reduce(function(acc, val){
                var accKey = val[objKey]
                acc = Object.assign({}, acc)
                if ( acc.hasOwnProperty(accKey) ){
                    acc[accKey] = acc[accKey] + totalInvoice(val)
                } else {
                    acc[accKey] = totalInvoice(val)
                }
                return acc
}, {})

var sumByCountry = groupAndSumBy("MARKET")

var vals =[
    {
        "COUNTRY": "AUSTRIA",
        "TYPE": "SERVICES",
        "AMT1": 2555.05,
        "AMT2": 2686.48,
        "AMT3": 2805.1,
        "AMT4": 2732.23
    },
    {
        "COUNTRY": "GERMANY",
        "TYPE": "SERVICES",
        "AMT1": 2555.05,
        "AMT2": 2686.48,
        "AMT3": 2805.1,
        "AMT4": 2732.23
    },
    {
        "COUNTRY": "UK",
        "TYPE": "SERVICES",
        "AMT1": 2555.05,
        "AMT2": 2686.48,
        "AMT3": 2805.1,
        "AMT4": 2732.23
    },
]
```

the desired output is as follows

```
sumByCountry(vals)

{
    'AUSTRIA': 10778.86,
    'GERMANY': 10777.86,
    'UK': 10777.86,
}
```

additionally, I would like to break the desired output above into separate records, which I haven't been able to achieve with ramda.

```
[
    {index:'AUSTRIA', value: 10777.86},
    {index:'GERMANY', value: 10777.86},
    {index:'UK', value: 10777.86}
]
```

Comment: You really don't need an `if/else` or the Object.assign() copy of `acc`

Comment: there may be more countries than just the three, it could range, and I don't want to specify it in the initial value of the reducer function, but rather build it . . . however if you know otherwise would be happy to know

Comment: Realize that ... can just do `acc[c[ObjKey]] = acc[c[ObjKey]] || {}`. Then update `acc[c[ObjKey]]` on next line

Comment: Please note that abstracting conditional statements by a function doesn't buy you anything in this case. This only makes sense if you want to use such statements as expressions, that is passing them around like data. Or if you want to use them like functions, that is partially apply them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first define a function that sums the properties of an object if they are numbers:

```
const sumObj = compose(sum, values, filter(is(Number)));

sumObj({
  "COUNTRY": "AUSTRIA",
  "TYPE": "SERVICES",
  "AMT1": 2555.05,
  "AMT2": 2686.48,
  "AMT3": 2805.1,
  "AMT4": 2732.23
});
//=> 10778.86
```

Then you could use `reduceBy` to group your objects together by `COUNTRY` and apply `sumObj` on each. After that use `aggregate` to destructure your object into individual records:

```js
var vals = [
  { "COUNTRY": "AUSTRIA",
    "TYPE": "SERVICES",
    "AMT1": 2555.05,
    "AMT2": 2686.48,
    "AMT3": 2805.1,
    "AMT4": 2732.23 },

  { "COUNTRY": "AUSTRIA",
    "TYPE": "SERVICES",
    "AMT1": 2555.05,
    "AMT2": 2686.48,
    "AMT3": 2805.1,
    "AMT4": 2732.23 },

  { "COUNTRY": "GERMANY",
    "TYPE": "SERVICES",
    "AMT1": 2555.05,
    "AMT2": 2686.48,
    "AMT3": 2805.1,
    "AMT4": 2732.23 },

  { "COUNTRY": "UK",
    "TYPE": "SERVICES",
    "AMT1": 2555.05,
    "AMT2": 2686.48,
    "AMT3": 2805.1,
    "AMT4": 2732.23 } ];

const sumObj = compose(sum, values, filter(is(Number)));
const sumObjs = reduceBy((acc, obj) => acc + sumObj(obj), 0, prop('COUNTRY'));
const aggregate = compose(map(zipObj(['index', 'value'])), toPairs, sumObjs);

console.log(

  aggregate(vals)

)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {map, zipObj, reduceBy, prop, compose, sum, applySpec, values, filter, is, toPairs} = R;</script>
```

Comment: this is a nice solution, but it doesn't account for if there are multiple records for AUSTRIA, I need to have them all consolidated.

Answer (score 1):

Aran!
I think you'll need to use lambda anyways, but if you'd like to change `if` statement to Ramda's one, may be this could be the solution?
It is a little bit smarter, but the choice is on you.

```js
const groupAndSumBy = objKey =>
  R.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const invoice = totalInvoice(val)
    const accKey = val[objKey]

    return R.ifElse(
      R.has(accKey),
      R.assoc(accKey, invoice + acc[accKey]),
      R.assoc(accKey, invoice)
    )(acc)
  }, {})
```

This function will prepare the results to the format you need:

```js
const groupAndSumBy = objKey => vals => R.pipe(
  R.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const invoice = totalInvoice(val)
    const accKey = val[objKey]

    return R.ifElse(
      R.has(accKey),
      R.assoc(accKey, invoice + acc[accKey]),
      R.assoc(accKey, invoice)
    )(acc)
  }, {}),
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(p => ({ index: p[0], value: p[1] }))
)(vals)
```

Comment: can you maybe provide the function to have the output as `{index: 'AUSTRIA', value: 324123}` after receiving the initial output ?

Comment: @AranFreel, appended the answer with the solution.